# An error occurred while calling o137.partitions. : org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://ip

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, amazon-emr

I am trying to execute this github project in an aws emr spark cluster
https://github.com/pran4ajith/spark-twitter-streaming.git

I've succeeded to run 2 fisrt codes

- tweet_stream_producer.py
- sparkml_train_model.py

But when I run consumer part with command

```
spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.0.0,io.delta:delta-core_2.12:0.7.0 tweet_stream_consumer.py
```

I got file path error

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o137.partitions.
: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://ip-10-0-0-61.ec2.internal:8020/home/hadoop/spark-twitter-streaming/TwitterStreaming/src/app/models/metadata
```

It seems that the problem is located mapping between local file system path and hadoop file system path

```
model_path = str(SRC_DIR / 'models')

pipeline_model = PipelineModel.load(model_path)
```

Comment: HDFS doesn't have a `/home` path. Please share your SRC_DIR variable

Comment: SRC_DIR = /home/hadoop/spark-twitter-streaming/TwitterStreaming/src/app/                 but consumer program try to load a model from path : hdfs://my_local_IP_address//home/hadoop/spark-twitter-streaming/TwitterStreaming/src/app/model/metadata/

Comment: Like I said, `/home` doesn't exist in HDFS. Spark tries to read HDFS paths by default

Comment: Well, how can I change my code according HDFS path?                                                                           model_path = str(SRC_DIR / 'models')
pipeline_model = PipelineModel.load(model_path)